# copy_from_user() runs in user space or kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

copy_from_user() is used in kernel module. So my understanding is it runs in kernel space.
however, I get confused after I read this "User context only. This function may sleep."
Can anybody give me an explanation?

Comment: It is a kernel space function, running in user context. Space (user/kernel) and context (user aka process/interrupt) are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "user context" doesn't refer to user space execution. It refers to kernel code running in the context of a particular user process. There has to be a relevant user process for the `from` argument to be meaningful.

Quoting [this web page](http://www.linuxgrill.com/anonymous/fire/netfilter/kernel-hacking-HOWTO-2.html) (which I found with a quick Google search for "linux user context"):

> There are two contexts (patterns of execution flow) in the Linux
>   kernel: interrupt and user(space) contexts. User contexts are code
>   which is entered from userspace: a system call. Unless the kernel code
>   sleeps for some reason (explicitly allowing other code to run), no
>   other user context will run on that CPU; this is the non-preemtive
>   part. They are always associated with a particular process.
>
> However, an interrupt can occur at **any** time, which halts the user
>   context in its tracks and runs an interrupt context. This is not
>   associated with any process; it is caused by a timer, an external
>   hardware interrupt, or a bottom-half (bottom halves may be run off the
>   timer or other interrupts, see below). When it is finished, the user
>   context will resume.

(In comments, 0x90 suggests that this quote is misleading, which may well be correct.)

Comment: I think the quote is totally misleading. There are kernel thread, irq, softirq contexts and user-thread. from the quote one can think wrongly if the kernel runs on non user execution flow it is in irq context which is totally wrong!

Comment: @0x90: Then I suggest you post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"User context" means here that when this function is called inside the kernel, the CPU must be in a state where it is configured to use a memory map associated with a user process. This map is specific to each process and basically has a range mapped to the kernel memory and a range mapped to the user process memory. This is why `copy_from_user` is able to copy bytes from the memory range of the process into a memory buffer in the kernel memory.

In some cases, for exemple when handling an interrupt, the CPU uses a different memory mapping in which there is no range for a user process, therefore `copy_from_user` doesn't make any sense.